# An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04, .net-core-2.0

I wrote a .net core console application on mac and it's working fine. Then I made a build for ubuntu by using

`dotnet build --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64`

the result was:

```
MyAppName.Server                MyAppName.Server.runtimeconfig.dev.json
MyAppName.Server.deps.json      MyAppName.Server.runtimeconfig.json
MyAppName.Server.dll            libhostfxr.so
MyAppName.Server.pdb            libhostpolicy.so
```

I copied these files on my linux server and run the following command

`dotnet MyAppName.Server.dll`

And now I getting

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyAppName.Server.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Ether.Network', version: '2.0.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Ether.Network.dll'
```

Ether.Network is the only package that I using.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [`dotnet build`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x):

> If the project has third-party dependencies, such as libraries from NuGet, they're resolved from the NuGet cache and aren't available with the project's built output. With that in mind, the product of dotnet build isn't ready to be transferred to another machine to run.

You want [`dotnet publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x) instead:

> The `dotnet publish` command's output is ready for deployment to a hosting system (for example, a server, PC, Mac, laptop) for execution and is the only officially supported way to prepare the application for deployment.